# Test multiple words with one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression and I want to pass it multiple words and give me back as a result the string that matches the expression. How can I do this (with vanilla JS, no jQuery etc.)?

```
let regEx = /\^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
let str1 = "5"
let str2 = "df-df-01"
let solutions = [str1,str2].HOW(regEx) //I'd like this to return ["df-df-01"]
```

Comment: `\^` matches `^` char. What is the pattern you need to match? If the pattern is just alphanumerics and `-`, use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: Look at [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `filter` + `test`:

```js
let regEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
let str1 = "5"
let str2 = "df-df-01"

let solutions = [str1,str2].filter(x => regEx.test(x)) 
// or .filter(/./.test.bind(regEx)) to make your teammates hate you

console.log(solutions)
```

Also note the fixed regexp.